# how to display flash message to ask select a list from listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, messagebox

can u guys check this code for me?
i want to try display flash message if the user dont select any options from the listbox

```
Public Sub btnHVM_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHVM.Click

        ListBoxHVM.Visible = True
        Code =ListBoxHVM.SelectedValue 

        If Code = "" Then

            Dim Message As String = "Please make a selection"
            MessageBox.Show(Message)

        End If    
If Code = "B" Then

            ChooseB1(Station)
            ChooseB2(Station)

        End If

        If Code = "A" Then
            ChooseA1(Station)
            ChooseA2(Site)
            ChooseA3()
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: the listbox `ListBoxHVM` is only visible when you click `btnHVM` then how can u select item ??

Comment: ehm in my form, i dont have to click on btnHVM to make ListBoxHVM visible. isnt that visible means that it visible all the time???

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign `ListBoxHVM.SelectedValue` to `code`

```
 Code=ListBoxHVM.SelectedValue
```

Edit 2

```
 If code = "" Then
```

Comment: and the rest are okay??

Comment: @lemon `ListBoxHVM.Visible = True` when `btnHVM_Click` event then how this will work ??

Comment: @LifeRunsOnCode Dammnn.. Forget that also -.-

Comment: @lemon if im not mistaken -1 means null or empty

Comment: @LifeRunsOnCode did u mean by, we need to click the button first??

Comment: @zayya -1 never was null before . Null means no value '-1' is a value. null means '' (nothing)

Comment: @zayya based on the code you wrote you will always gonna get `"Please make a selection"` message

Comment: @zayya does your `ListBoxHVM` is visible and you can select item on your `ListBoxHVM` before you click `btnHVM` ?

Comment: @LifeRunsOnCode yes, it is visible all the time

Comment: @zayya so why did you set `ListBoxHVM.Visible = True` on `btnHVM_click`and one more thing i want to know that have you selected any item in `ListBoxHVM ` before you click on `btnHVM `